# Creating a shortcut to IE in a Visual Studio Setup Project

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer, installation, project, shortcut

I'm creating the installer for a Silverlight app of ours. The app will run on the local machine, in internet explorer in kiosk mode and will be started from a desktop shortcut. 
I'm having trouble creating the shortcut with my Setup Project in VS 2008. What I need to end up with is a shortcut on the desktop with this

*"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -k [ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer][ProductName]\MySilverlightHostPage.html*

as the target. I'd also like my own icon on it if possible. Any ideas? I've tried a couple of different ways to do this but nothings quite right.

Answer (score 2):

i tried this and it worked:
-manually create a shortcut anywhere in your file system with specifying the target you want and set its icon -in your setup project right click on your setup project. select view->file system. right click on File System On Target Machine, select Add Special Folder->User's Desktop. right click on User's Desktop, select Add->File. Select the shortcut you've created before. This shortcut will be added to the User's Desktop.

after your installation this shortcut will appear on the user's desktop with your selected icon and uninstalling the application will remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Deskliter utility which will "wrap" your XAP and generate a EXE file that you can use to run your Silverlight application on the desktop as a "kiosk" application: http://blendables.com/labs/Desklighter/Default.aspx.

There are also rumors going on about SL3 supporting off line. Check it out at http://blogs.zdnet.com/Stewart/?p=769 - Nothing confirmed yet, but will be interesting to follow.

Comment: Desklighter is interesting. I hadn't come across that before. There doesn't seem to be much I can do with it myself though - with IE I can lock a lot of it down so the user can't get out (it really is a true kiosk application). Probably further away from where I am now